# Disqus & AJAX-loaded articles

Tags: javascript, ajax, disqus

How do i load disqus threads on these two articles ?

http://example.com/NewInvestmentEducation/InvestmentEducationMainPage.aspx#Types#CashEquivalents

and

http://example.com/NewInvestmentEducation/InvestmentEducationMainPage.aspx#Types#Learning

Both the pages are loaded through AJAX from http://example.com/NewInvestmentEducation/InvestmentEducationMainPage.aspx

I tried some workarounds but i'm getting the same disqus thread every time i load these pages, even though i did change the diqus_identifier and disqus_url variables in JS.

pls, help me out.

Comment: i added the reset code from http://docs.disqus.com/help/85/ and loaded it after placing the ajax call for the webpage.

Comment: edit your question and add a sample of your code

Comment: is with disqus_identifier this set the url, disqus identify the post for it.